# Find model deleted from QGIS processing toolbox

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler, delete

Using Windows 10 with QGIS 3.26.1., I successfully save a model from QGIS and added it to the Processing Toolbox. I then wanted to remove it from Processing Toolbox by right clicking on the model in the Toolbox > Delete Model... (no. 1 on screenshot).

It seems the model is not just deleted from the toolbox, bot from the folder as well. I have made some changes in the model that I still need, but could not find the model in the folder it was saved to. In the recycle bin I was also not able to find the model to restore it. It was saved to the folder:

```
C:\Users\[current user]\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\english\processing\models
```

Is there a possibility to restore the model?

[image]

*Screenshot, showing the confirmation of model saved. I deleted the model in the Processing toolbox - right side, no. 1:*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. As you discovered, models deleted in QGIS do not go to the recycle bin. I use a backup service that's similar to Dropbox and allows me to restore both deleted files as well as previous versions of files.

Comment: Not a solution, but a valid answer - to know that it doesn't work is still good to know.